# Running Linux Functions inside Sqlplus

Tags: linux, oracle, sqlplus

Can I call user-created shell functions from inside Oracle SQLPLUS using the `HOST` command? If not, what's the best way to approach the problem?

Essentially, I want to run a shell file:

```
Shell commands
sqlplus
@file.sql
HOST mylinuxfunction...
@file2.sql
HOST anotherlinuxfunction..
exit
Shell commands
```

Thank you!

Comment: what does it cost to try it and see?

Comment: I wish I could, but I'm locked out. I'm just an intern with no access to anything.

Comment: If you are locked out with no access to anything, then it's rather a moot point.  @Mark Stewart makes some good points, but here is where we'd need to step back and ask what problem you are really trying to solve, instead of focusing on a particular technique.  If it's just to lean you can create your own test system on your own computer. Install VirtualBox, create a vm, configure it with Oracle Linux, and install an Oracle db on that.  Web is full of info on how.

Answer (score 0):

You can surely invoke HOST commands from SQLPlus scripts, but I imagine *you are really asking* whether you can use the return values from your linux functions in the rest of your SQLPlus scripts.  And you also might be wanting to use results from the SQL queries in your linux functions.

If you do **not** need to pass SQL information to your linux functions, and do **not** need to access the results from the linux functions in the remainder of your SQL, then what you have will almost work.  This would

```
date
sqlplus / << xxENDxx \
    @file.sql
    HOST mylinuxfunction...
    @file2.sql
    HOST anotherlinuxfunction..
    exit
xxENDxx
date
```

Now if you want to get information from your linux function into SQL, you will have to use external tables; a lot of setup, but look here:   https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:439619916584 and search for "but here is another interesting approach, available in 10.2.0.5 and up:"

If you want to pass information from Linux commands that are done before invoking SQLPlus into your SQL commands, that would be something like this, that inserts a row into the uptimes table with output from the `uptime` command that is stored in the BASH variable `$UPTIMES`:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$1" = "" ]
then
    echo Missing User ID parm
    exit 1
else
    USER_ID=$1
fi

read  -p "Enter Your password for Oracle instance $ORACLE_SID for user $USER_ID: " PW

UPTIMES=`uptime | awk -F,  '{print $3, $4, $5}' | awk '{printf "%2.2f,%2.2f,%2.2f\n", $3, $4, $5}'`
sqlplus /nolog << xxENDxx \

connect $USER_ID/$PW

        insert into uptimes (date_stamp, one_min, five_min, fifteen_min) values (sysdate, $UPTIMES);
        HOST ls -o uptimes.sh
        --@file2.sql
        select * from uptimes;
        HOST du -sh .
        exit
xxENDxx

date
```

Invoking the above gives this:

```
oracle. (/home/oracle/sql)
Linux> ./uptimes.sh mark.stewart
Enter Your password for Oracle instance ecs03 for user mark.stewart: xxxx

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Thu Mar 17 20:09:36 2016
Dev:@> Connected.
Dev:MARK.STEWART@ecs03> Dev:MARK.STEWART@ecs03>
1 row created.

Dev:MARK.STEWART@ecs03> -rwxr-xr-x. 1 oracle 548 Mar 17 20:09 uptimes.sh

Dev:MARK.STEWART@ecs03> Dev:MARK.STEWART@ecs03>
DATE_STAM    ONE_MIN   FIVE_MIN FIFTEEN_MIN
--------- ---------- ---------- -----------
17-MAR-16          0        .01         .05
17-MAR-16          0        .01         .05
17-MAR-16          0        .01         .05

Dev:MARK.STEWART@ecs03>  146M    .

Dev:MARK.STEWART@ecs03> Disconnected from Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options
Thu Mar 17 20:09:36 CET 2016
oracle. (/home/oracle/sql)
Linux>
```